# User authentication using Keycloak via Kerberos on Windows Server 2008

Tags: java, authentication, windows-server-2008, kerberos, keycloak

I'm trying to set up user authentication mechanism for my website using Keycloak and Kerberos protocol. I have followed instructions from here: http://matthewcasperson.blogspot.com/2015/07/authenticating-via-kerberos-with.html

But after setting it up like that, I'm still prompted to fill login form. When I fill up the user name and password I can login to my application, but of course it doesn't meet my needs. The whole authentication should be done once, when user logs to the operating system, so when he go to the website should be authenticated automatically by Kerberos without any login form.

I have found settings which are not mentioned in this tutorial, but I think it makes a little progress. In Keycloak configuration menu I have changed Authentication Flow for Browser Kerberos from alternative to required. [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tASB.png).

But after that when I'm going to my web page I got message **"Kerberos is not set up. You cannot login."** This is really confusing because all my settings seems to be good, and that kind of error does say nothing. 
I found in a keycloak source code that this message is shown probably when SPNEGO token is wrong.

```
 UserCredentialModel spnegoCredential = UserCredentialModel.kerberos(spnegoToken);
```

Had someone similar problem, or has any idea how to solve it?